# Committing multiple object in one go

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I have a situation where I use force.com sites to run a shopping cart. During the first 5 pages of the shopping cart, I gather the data such as credit card number shipping address, etc.

The last button is called "Place Order". This is where I want to commit everything to the database and charge the credit card. So here is the order of execution:

```
1) Insert an account.
2) Charge the credit card using a call out webservice.
3) If the charge worked, create a Receipt__c object which is a slave object on the Account.
4) Create a pdf of the Receipt__c object.
5) Display the pdf in an iframe of the client's browser.
```

Now, apex code cannot call a webservice if I have DML process executing. So I had to move the process in two buttons.

Second, apex code cannot generate the pdf until the receipt is DML insert is fully executed into the database.

The end result is that the customer has to click 3 buttons in quick succession in order to process all the statements. This is problematic since 1 click button is the way to go since 1999. Is there a way to process all of this in a single apex code execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can did Something like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="action1" action="{!action1}" rerender="message" oncomplete="action2()" />
<apex:actionFunction name="action2" action="{!action2}" rerender="message" />
<input value="Save" class="btn" onclick="action1();" type="button" />
```